# Gource with github

Tags: git, github, visualization, gource

Well, recently, I was doing a project on GitHub and I have done good progress in it so far, so I wanted to make a visualization for change log, there is more than 2 people in the project, so I made my researches and found there is something called Gource, I could not find good tutorials about using it with git repositories, I have tried YouTube videos etc. But I came up with nothing, so hopefully you guys can help with this, assuming the repository path is: `https://github.com/xxxx/yyyy`

Comment: Have you tried ... `gource repo_path` where `repo_path` is your local clone?!

Comment: i am new to this kind of things :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gource is run locally on your machine and is meant to analyse the history of local repositories.

Therefore, you need to clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxx/yyyy.git
```

Then run gource on the root folder:

```
gource yyyy
```